# GoogleWeb Fonts - Declare font variable with fonts in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
var fonts = [];
    $.get("https://www.googleapis.com/webfonts/v1/webfonts?key=AIzaSyBJ9zGTIOTxFHbAwdPJG9cAXmsP-h3mhzY", callbackFuncWithData)
    function callbackFuncWithData(data)
      {
        $.each(data.items, function (index, value) {
          fonts += value.family;
        });

      }
```

I tried different ways to reach populated "fonts" variable but it won't work.

```js
  console.log(fonts, "my var");
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not how you insert values into your array:

```
var fonts = [];
fonts += value.family;
```

You need to use `.push` method:

```js
var fonts = [];

$.get("https://www.googleapis.com/webfonts/v1/webfonts?key=AIzaSyBJ9zGTIOTxFHbAwdPJG9cAXmsP-h3mhzY", callbackFuncWithData);

function callbackFuncWithData(data)
{
  $.each(data.items, function (index, value) {
    fonts.push(value.family); // <-- that's how you insert values :)
  });

  // Just an example output. Don't copy it to your code:
  document.body.innerText = JSON.stringify(fonts);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```